# jasper report missing characters

Tags: utf-8, jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports* report with *DejaVu Sans Font*. When I try to print the word `emissão` it not print properly shows some missing characters, with `Locale=pt`

I am sure that all properties file is in *UTF-8* format.

The *jxml* file is also in *UTF-8* format. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Is there any missing setting?

Is font support *UTF-8*?

Comment: Did you use the [Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)?

Comment: No, I use default fonts which is already available in jasperreport_font.jar. so I think no need to add externally.

Comment: I think either Jasper compiler or pdf exporter cannot detect UTF-8

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530595/problem-utf-8-encoding-i18n-files this is a same problem I found. resources read in default ASCII format not in UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this happens but my solution is put `emission = emiss\u00E3o` in resource properties file instead of `emission = emissão` may be jasper report lib read resource file bytes only in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked this link? [Unicode Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/unicode/)
It says that changing the encoding from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 should be enough. There is also a custom property "net.sf.jasperreports.export.character.encoding". Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to set pdfEncoding property on textElement like this:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="554" height="30" uuid="faf3ff08-ecbc-40cb-b82c-529428aadaa4"/>
    <textElement>
         <font size="8" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{disclaimer}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Cp1250 corresponds to [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) which is used for Central European countries e.g. Poland. After setting this property characters came back. I guess it should be possible to do this also for other encodings.